# Shell how to use a command on every file in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So what I have to do is find all regular files within and below the directory. For each of these regular files, I have to egrep for pattern($ARG) and find out if the output of the file matches the pattern ($ARG), if it does it will add one to the counter.

What I have so far is the file command:

```
 $count = 0
 file *
```

However, I am having trouble getting egrep &ARG > /dev/null/ ; echo $? to run through each file that appears from (file *).

I understand that file * | egrep directory > /dev/null ; echo $? will output 0 because it find the pattern 'directory' in the file, but am having trouble getting it to loop through each regular file so I can add one to the counter every time the pattern is matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear, but if you're looking for number of files containing a pattern

```
grep -l "pattern" * 2>/dev/null | wc -l
```

will give you that.  Errors are ignored coming from directories.

If you want recursively do the complete tree including dot files

```
grep -r -l "pattern" | wc -l
```

Comment: You need `-r` to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: @Aleksej: May I ask you why exactly you deleted my answer? You claimed that it did not provide an answer to the question. I think it does: The OP asked for a program to solve a particular problem, and I posted one. If you think that my program does not fulfil the requirements of the OP (which, of course, is possible - I never claimed to make no errors in programming), it would have been better if you had pointed out this error instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
counter=0
find /path/to/directory/ -type f | \
    while read file
    do
        if grep -i -e -q "$pattern" "$file"
        then counter=$((counter+1))
        fi
    done
echo "$counter"
```

Comment: $counter will still be zero because the while loop is in a pipeline

Comment: Also, you have `-q` as the argument to `-e`

Comment: -q denotes exit with 0 if match found, and if any match is found then the counter will be incremented. I have skipped the if else condition's square brackets to make the code more cleaner.

Comment: I'm aware of that and I applaud you for using it. But you need `-q -e "$pattern"` or `-e "$pattern" -q` -- don't put -q between -e and its argument.

Comment: However your answer (and the accepted one) are fundamentally wrong: see my first comment and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 0):

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

```
counter=0
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in **; do
    grep -qiE "$pattern" "$file" && ((counter++))
done
echo "$counter"
```

If you want to include hidden files, add `shopt -s dotglob`